# How to Change Pivot Header Template in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I would like to be able to change the background of the Pivot Headers and Application Title in Windows Phone 8. From what I gather, I must create a custom style targeting the Pivot control. I am not sure, however, to change the background of only the headers?

I would like to adjust the style somehow

```
<Style x:Key="MyPivotStyle" TargetType="phone:Pivot">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:Pivot">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid CacheMode="BitmapCache" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/bg_header.png"/>
                    </Grid.Background>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Grid.Row="2" />
                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Margin="24,17,0,-7">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/Assets/company_name.png" Width="213.75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="140,-20,0,35" BorderThickness="0" x:Name="btnHome">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/btnHome.png" Width="48" Height="48" ></Image>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ContentPresenter>
                <controlsPrimitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement" Foreground="White"  Grid.Row="1"/>
                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: I would suggest [this solution from 2012](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2012/05/23/Changing-the-background-color-of-your-pivot-headers.aspx), but looks like Iris has it covered

Answer (score 33, accepted):

EDITED for WinRT (sorry for the delay and thanks for the reminder to update this answer):
To edit a full template right click on the control when in Document Outline and select Edit Template - Current (in Visual Studio or Blend) and the template will be generated for you and you can edit as you want, [see my answer here for screenshots.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038921/change-style-for-all-listboxitem-in-a-listbox-windows-phone-8/16040188#16040188)

Here are the two examples below (posted in 2013) redone for Windows Phone Windows Runtime:
[image]

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Pivot Title="Re-templating example">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Blue">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <Pivot.TitleTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Green">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.TitleTemplate>
        <PivotItem Header="One">
            <TextBlock FontSize="35"
                        Text="This is item one" />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="Two">
            <TextBlock FontSize="35"
                        Text="This is item 2" />
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

And second example, notice that we are wrapping the ContentPresenter in a Grid (you could use a border as well or any other element):

[image]

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PivotBackground" Color="#FFE46C08"/>

    <Style x:Key="PivotStyle" TargetType="Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Pivot">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--Notice that ContentControl is wrapped in a Grid and Background set to resource furtehr up-->
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{StaticResource PivotBackground}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="TitleContentControl" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{StaticResource PivotTitleContentControlStyle}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                            <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <!--Background set to resource further up-->
                                <PivotHeaderPanel Background="{StaticResource PivotBackground}" x:Name="Header" >
                                    <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform" TranslateX="0"/>
                                    </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                </PivotHeaderPanel>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter">
                                    <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" X="0"/>
                                    </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ItemsPresenter>
                            </PivotPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Using the above style:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Pivot Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle}"
            Title="Re-templating example">
        <PivotItem Header="One">
            <TextBlock FontSize="35" Text="This is item one" />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="Two">
            <TextBlock FontSize="35" Text="This is item 2"/>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

By the way, it's usually preferred to keep styles in a separate style file- I've only kept them on the same page for simplicity for this example. If you remove the x:key attribute the style will be applied to all the controls of the set target type (Pivot in this example).

**Answer from 2013 for Windows Phone 7.X and Windows Phone 8 (WP Silverlight:**

There are a few ways you can do it, but here is one example:

[image]

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>  
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <phone:Pivot Grid.Row="1">
        <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Red" Height="200">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <phone:PivotItem Header="Test">
            <TextBlock Text="ghjgb"/>
        </phone:PivotItem>
        <phone:PivotItem Header="Test">
            <TextBlock Text="ghjgb"/>
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

If you however want to do this:

[image]

You can do this, remove the x:key to apply to all pivoits, or use the key to set the style on just selected pivoit elements like so:

```
<controls:Pivot Title="The Marathon Runner" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle}">
    <Style x:Key="PivotStyle" TargetType="phone:Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:Pivot">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Background="#ff9000" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CacheMode="BitmapCache"
        Grid.Row="2" />
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Margin="24,17,0,-7"/>
                        <Primitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement"
                                          Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter"
                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Dont forget to use:

```
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:Primitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
```

Comment: My goal is to have the entire background of the pivot headers and application title the same color while the text foreground remains the same. I think the best way to describe it is everything above and including the pivot headers, a single color, while the background of each pivot item is another. I've tested your method but it only changes the background of each pivot header title. I added an example of the style from the Pivot, but I am not sure of how to change this to adjust the header backgrounds?

Comment: Have a look at the image and code I added to the post, is it something like that you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to accomplish. I set the style although you are using `Controls:Pivot` which I believe is for WP7 and I am using `phone:Pivot` for WP8. This leads to my next question, I get an error on statement `controlsPrimitives:PivotHeadersControl`.

Comment: It's the same xaml, but to clarify I added the namespaces you need. phone: and Controls: are just aliases, you can set them to whatever you want. It's just a way to have a short way to reference a namespace. For a long read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx

Comment: Excellent. With a bit of tweaking I'm sure I can get what I Need. Love the pink hair.

Comment: One more question, if I need my app title to be on the left, like how it is in the default Pivot Application, where would I make that change? Right now it is centered.

Comment: Note that changes to HeaderTemplate don't always appear updated in the preview window until after you run the app.

Comment: I used this solution for a WP8 app but it doesn't work for 8.1. Any pointers?

Comment: I am trying to use the solution (the one with the orange backgroud)=  in a Universal App 8.1 project: however, even if I am working on the Windows Phone project and I use a specific style file in it, I got these errors even if I put xmlns:primitives="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives" 
 Obviously I have a reference in my project to the Windows Phone 8.1 dll

Error 12 The name "PivotHeaderItem" does not exist in the namespace "Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives". 

Error 4 PivotHeaderItem is not supported in a Windows Phone project.

Comment: I'll take a look at this later tonight and update the answer with a 8.1 version :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot about this Enzo & Royston- you probably figured it out by, now but I've updated the answer now. Happy coding!

Comment: Hey @IrisClasson - Thanks for the write up, but how do I move the headers to the bottom of the window instead of it being at the top?