# Swipe Between Pages (ViewPager) On WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I Would like to  move between pages in my application through swiping.

Here is a picture  to explain my example :

[image]

Let's say that I have 3 Pages represented each by 3 tabs how can I swipe to move from one to another?

Comment: you can use a pivot or a panorama control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot control is what you need. However its not used to swipe between pages just child controls of this control but it will work for what you need.
And for customizing header you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902064/how-to-change-pivot-header-template-in-windows-phone-8).

You can just use Pivot control as I mentioned and remove the header of pivot by keeping it empty or whatever and put a control of yours made with borders and all stuff and you can show and hide the highlight on the basis of index of the pivot control. Basically using the pivot control as you would have and instead of its header you put your control up there made up of grid control and `OnIndexChanged` event of pivot control you manipulate it to get a feel of what you want.

Comment: I  am looking for an alternative of Pivot Control, like the one that  I described on Android Platforms. The twitter app in Windows Phone uses the feature that I describe for example.

Comment: @user2505650 Do you want to code it yourself or looking for a prebuilt solution?

Comment: If there is a pre built solution i would like to look for it, but I am looking as well to code it myself, so if you have any ideas for which path to take or from where to begin that would be really helpful

Comment: @user2505650 check my edited answer and let me know if you still have any doubts.

Comment: So for Example if I have  those Three Titles :  "Music" ,  "Cinema" , "Theatre"  with a picture for each Title , How can I make them appear in the page in the same time. Because in pivot Items Only the first title appears completely and then the second one is cut, i you see what I mean , So I would like all my titles to appear in the same line

Comment: @user2505650 You don't have to reply on the titles of pivot control, keep them empty. Put your own titles and change the appearance of them in `SelectionChanged` event of pivot control based on the `selected index` property.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows phone for achieving the same you have to make a customize control

but if you don't want to make then you could use panorama and pivot control provide by windows phone.