# change the position of an Pivot header (Windows phone)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, panorama-control, pivotviewer

Is there a possibility to Change the Pivot Header of an Windows Phone app so that it Looks like an Panorama element Header (i am also ok with an Panorama Element without an preview to the next item on the right side)

I searched already for a while, but couldn't find stuft that fits for me.  hope you can help me thx

Comment: Why can't you use a Panorama instead of a Pivot?

Comment: i can use a Panorama instead, but then i would have to change the item template, because i dont want to see the next item on the right side of the Screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HeaderTemplate for Pivot.
Examples: http://chillijam.co.uk/2012/01/11/alter-a-pivot-controls-header-template-the-easy-way-wp7/ and
 [How to Change Pivot Header Template in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902064/how-to-change-pivot-header-template-in-windows-phone-8)