# Actionbar component for Windows Phone

Tags: facebook, twitter, android-actionbar, windows-phone

In facebook and twitter apps for Windows Phone they use at the top of the screens something similar to the android actionbar component. Is there a component in Windows Phone similar to the actionbar in android?

Comment: Twitter uses the Pivot control, which you also have in your messages app for example. You can customize the Pivot header using XAML (see example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902064/how-to-change-pivot-header-template-in-windows-phone-8 ) to change the text to some icons, which you can style as you want.

Comment: Thank you @sibbl, I tested the behavior of the twitter and facebook apps and I noticed that as you said, they use a pivot. Thank you, now I now that the most of the job is about styles.