# What the name of type of this Menu

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Can anyone tell me what is the name of the style of this menu? (The menu like Facebook app in Windows Phone - not Slide left menu).

I try to search "Slide Menu" but can't find any examples like this.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if that kind of menu has a name UX-wise, but technically speaking on WP it's a pivot control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone this type of control doesn't exist, but you can create it yourself very quickly!

Just add a grid(the container of the sections' icons) and an empty Pivot Control below. In my case I added the pivot and the pivotItems in the code behind, each section was an user control.
If you plan to add pivot and pivotItems in XAML, probably you also need to modify the pivot's header template to make it empty (see here how: [How to Change Pivot Header Template in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902064/how-to-change-pivot-header-template-in-windows-phone-8))

Then register for the selectionChanged event of the pivot control and modify the appearance of the grid above accordingly to the current selectedItem.

So when the user swipe, selectionChanged is fired, inside the event handler get the selectedItem/selectedIndex and highlight the right icon in the icons' grid.

If something isn't clear feel free to ask, maybe I can provide you also an example

Comment: Was my answer helpfull?

Answer (score 0):

You can create this by adding a control named **SlideView** which you will find on **NuGet Packet Manager** by searching "**SlideView.Library**".
In this you have to add grid as much as you want.
It also contains **OnSelectionChanged** Event.
You can add title grid in each main grid with different selected option in **Red Selection Effect**.

```
<library:SlideView x:Name="SlideView" IsSlideEnabled="True" SelectedIndex="0">
<Grid>
    ....... Display Post .......
</Grid>
<Grid>
    ....... People List .......
</Grid>
<Grid>
    ....... Cart .......
</Grid></library:SlideView>
```